# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a few rocks for the game asteroid and I am receiving this error message. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
class Rock(movable.Movable):
# outline = [(10, 0), (12, 8), (0, 7), (-10, 10), (-5, 0), (-10, -10), 
(0, -8)]
outline = []
points = random.randint(5, 15)
for degrees in range(0, 360, int(360/points)):
    r = random.randint(5, 15)
    angle = math.radians(degrees)
    x = int(r * math.cos(angle))
    y = int(r * math.sin(angle))
    point = (x, y)
    outline.append(point)

x = random.randint(0, SCREENW)
y = random.randint(0, SCREENH)
d = random.randint(0, 359)
movable.Movable.__init__(outline, x, y, dir)
self.setColor(255, 0, 0)

dx = random.randint(1, 4) * random.randint(-1, 1)
dy = random.randint(1, 4) * random.randint(-1, 1)
self.setDX(7)
self.setDY(3)

ddir = random.randint(-20, 20)
self.rotate(ddir)

def paint(self, surface):
    pygame.draw.polygon(surface, (255, 0, 0), outline)
```

I just don't understand where a 'list' is being called?

Here is my Trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pygame_starter.py", line 4, in <module>
import game
File "/Volumes/KINGSTON/CS1410/Asteroids/game.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame, rocket
File "/Volumes/KINGSTON/CS1410/Asteroids/rocket.py", line 75, in 
<module>
class Rock(movable.Movable):
File "/Volumes/KINGSTON/CS1410/Asteroids/rocket.py", line 90, in Rock
movable.Movable.__init__(outline, x, y, dir)
File "/Volumes/KINGSTON/CS1410/Asteroids/movable.py", line 7, in 
__init__
locatable.Locatable.__init__(self, x, y)
File "/Volumes/KINGSTON/CS1410/Asteroids/locatable.py", line 6, in 
__init__
self.x = int(SCREENW//2)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Here is my Locatable:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = int(SCREENW//2)
    self.y = int(SCREENH//2)
    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0
    self.dir = 0
    self.ddir = 0
    self.life = True
    self.color = (0, 0, 255)
    self.radius = 0
```

Comment: Please include a complete error traceback in the question. Please also format the indentation of your code.

Comment: it goes back to my locatable, but it doesn't come up if I get rid of the rock class

Comment: What is the `__init__` for `locatable.Locatable`?

Comment: Your `Rock` class has a strange and probably incorrect structure. (Aside from being incorrectly formatted.) It does not have a constructor, it does not have any methods, and it does not have any `self` references.

Comment: And I suppose it's inheriting from `list`?

Comment: For starters, you still didn't include a few important pieces of code. Where exactly does `Rock.__init__` begin and end? What happens to the `movable` instance you have created (btw there is usually no reason to call superclass explicitly, that's what `super` does)? My best bet would be that you've mixed up argument order in `movable.__init__` and placed `outline` where `x` should go, but if you want people to answer your question, don't leave them guessing.

Comment: Lol this is how the professor had us put it together. I do completely understand why you are saying that.

Comment: What do you mean keep you guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is rather odd ... but the issue is almost certainly here:

```
movable.Movable.__init__(outline, x, y, dir)
```

The `__init__` method expects an instance of `movable.Movable` as the first parameter.  You are passing it `outline`, which is a list.